# Water level sensor XKC-25 on boat battery

Tags: power-supply, voltage, filter

I am working on a PCB that involves three [XKC-25-NPN](https://www.icstation.com/contact-liquid-level-sensor-ip67-waterproof-output-water-level-detector-p-12292.html)  12 V units on a boat.

I have a question about 12 V DC. When the motor is on the DC voltage can go over 12 V and reach 13.8 V.

How can I regulate and filter the DC power supply  without a lot of components to have a stable 12 V DC with no noise?

Basic specifications:

1. Input voltage: DC 5-12 V
2. Power consumption: 5 mA
3. Output voltage (high level): InVCC
4. Output voltage (low level): 0 V
5. Output current: 1-50 mA
6. Response time: 500 ms
7. Operating ambient temperature: 0~100 Celsius
8. Sensor thickness (sensitivity) range: 0-20 mm
9. Communication: NPN

Comment: The data available on those sensors makes me unhappy.  Most places advertise them as "5-12V" then mention that they are "5-24V."  The sellers don't appear to know or care what the sensors really need, and there's no real datasheet available.

Comment: You may not need to do anything.  The places selling those sensors often mention "5-24V" operation.  The difficulty being that I don't trust any of the places selling those sensors to actually know anything about them.

Comment: Ambitious specs = no sale.

Answer (score 1):

At 5 mA consumption, your best solution would be a 5 V linear regulator. AMS1117-5 and LM7805 are popular choices. You can get them as ready-made modules as well.

Comment: the problem for 5 volt is that i have an already 12 dc line that feed many others sensors.

Comment: I really want to filter this 12 dc supply noisy that arrive from the main boat battery

Comment: @KhalesNaim The 5 V regulator will do that for you.

Comment: @KhalesNaim Note also that the battery voltage can also drop below 12V anyway. An empty 12V battery is in the 11.5-11.7 V range.

Comment: No below  because the sensors work only when the motor run so the alternator will do the job anyway